# to find $p$ such that $p^2$ divides X where $X=a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3............\cdot a_n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We have $n$ numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,......,a_n$ a number $X=a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot a_3............\cdot a_n$.
We need to check if there exists some $p$ such that $p^2$ divides  $X$.

I came across a solution which says that if greatest common divisor $G$ of any pair among all pairwise numbers (a$i$,a$j$) is greater than 1 then that G can be one of our $P$.
however i could not figure out as how this is correct ?
I read square free numbers from this wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer
where it says that $N=a\cdot b$ is square free if both a and b are co prime .

Comment: Let $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(2,3,6)$; the GCD is 1, but - - -

Comment: The above comment seem to be about gcd of numbers being 1, but in the post the gcd G was said to be greater than 1. [And the post only claimed IF GCD>1 then such P has P^2 dividing X, look OK.]

Comment: I seem to have misinterpreted it. The post does not say it would be the greatest possible such $P$, but just some $P$. OK, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this we need there to be two or more numbers ($n \ge 2$). Let the first two be $a,b$ and assume the gcd $P$ of all the numbers is greater than $1.$ Since $P$ is a factor of each of $a,b$ we can write $a=Pk,\ b=Pk'.$ Then the product $X$ of all the numbers has the factor $a \cdot b=P^2 \cdot k k',$ so that $X$ is divisible by $P^2$ as desired.

Comment: Perfect reasoning.

Comment: Note the failure for only one number if that number is a prime $p$ (then GCD is $P=p>1,$ and the product is $X=p,$ but $P^2=p^2$ is not a divisor of $X.$) Same happens for one number which is squarefree and greater than 1.